# Elasticsearch newbie: Integrating with Rails and localhost:9200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, elasticsearch, localhost

Going to try and keep this short for readability. I need to integrate elasticsearch with Rails for a test app and did so following this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/

I came across the portion that says "Validate Installation

Open this url: http://localhost:9200 and you’ll see ElasticSearch respond like so: {
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Anvil",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.2.1",
    "build_hash" : "6c95b759f9e7ef0f8e17f77d850da43ce8a4b364",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-06-03T15:02:52Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.8"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

I am at a complete loss. I found some solutions online that tell me to run curl localhost:9200 and i'm getting the error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Would someone mind hinting at what I'm missing about this process that would allow me to run localhost9200 and get to the next steps of the tutorial? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sounds like elasticsearch isn't running - I don't remember if brew starts it automatically but `brew info elasticsearch` will tell you how to start it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last month I wrote a blog post on [`Add Robust Search functionality in your Rails 4 app using Elasticsearch and Typeahead JS`](https://sharvy.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/add-robust-search-functionality-in-your-rails-4-app-using-elasticsearch-and-typeahead-js/).

You can go through that post and see if it helps. That post helped many others who are new in Rails and using ElasticSearch for the first time.